# add_axes covers previous plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am making a 3D plot with two sets of axes (in particular, an animation for a rotating cone).

First, I make one set of axes using fig.add_subplot, and plot the rotating cone using ax.plot.

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
```

But when I add this declaration for ax2 after the above two lines (like below), I just see a white plot (no rotating cone).

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax2 = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), projection="3d", frame_on=False)
```

Can anyone help with what went wrong here? Why is what I plotted using ax get covered or erased when I declared an ax2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second plot background color is covering the first one. You can remove the background by doing:

```
ax2.patch.set_visible(False)
```

However, you will still see the second axes on top of the first one, and you will only be able to interact with the top axes and not the bottom one. Are you sure that's what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I'm not really sure about what I would want to interact with yet... so I think I will figure that out as I go.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. I do indeed want to interact with both. Would you happen to know how to do that?